# retrieve summed amounts from sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is the problem with the following query:

```
SELECT wbCode||yr, CAST(coalesce(Cons,0) AS FLOAT), wbCode
FROM Commodities
Where CCode in (2611,2513,2961) Group by wbCode||yr
```

I want the query above to return the sums for every wbCode in a given yr (USA1990), for example; but the code above is not summing up; it is retrieving the same data as:

```
SELECT wbCode||yr, CAST(coalesce(Cons,0) AS FLOAT), wbCode 
FROM Commodities
Where CCode in (2611) Group by wbCode||yr

SELECT wbCode||yr, CAST(coalesce(Cons,0) AS FLOAT), wbCode 
FROM Commodities Where CCode in (2513,2961)
Group by wbCode||yr
```

How can I get it to sum?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am using sqlite with pasw in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `||` ? Just group by them separately

```
SELECT wbCode, yr, SUM(CAST(coalesce(Cons,0) AS FLOAT)), wbCode
FROM Commodities
Where CCode in (2611,2513,2961)
Group by wbCode, yr
```

Or

```
SELECT wbCode||yr, SUM(CAST(coalesce(Cons,0) AS FLOAT)), wbCode
FROM Commodities
Where CCode in (2611,2513,2961)
Group by wbCode, yr
```

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using `SUM` function to aggregate results?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  SELECT wbCode
  ,      yr
  ,      SUM(CAST(coalesce(Cons,0) AS FLOAT))
    FROM Commodities
   WHERE CCode in (2611,2513,2961) 
GROUP BY wbCode
,        yr;
```